# avoiding nesting `Result<'T,'TError>`

Tags: error-handling, f#

Suppose we have this `input`:

```ml
let input =
    [
        "0.10"
        "0.21"
        "forty"
        "5.32"
        "q6.20"
    ]
```

Mapping this input to F# results leads to `Result<'T,'TError> list`:

```ml
open System

let output =
    input
    |> List.map (
        fun s ->
            match Decimal.TryParse s with
            | true, i -> Ok i
            | _ -> Error $"failed to parse `{s}`"
        )

output |> printf "%A"
```

```
[Ok 0.10M; Ok 0.21M; Error "failed to parse `forty`"; Ok 5.32M;
 Error "failed to parse `q6.20`"]
```

Is this is a generally accepted way to collect results?

Or, is there a concern for scalability and performance such that only one aggregate Result is returned for the entire list? Something like `Result<'T,'TError list>`? Would `FsToolkit.ErrorHandling` [[GitHub](https://github.com/demystifyfp/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling)] be available for this or am I missing a pattern baked into the language?

Would this solution handle lists of lists to avoid returning `Result<Result<'T,'TError> list>, 'TError>`?

Comment: It kinda depends on what your goal is. You could want a list of `Result`s or you could want to collect all the `Ok` elements and discard all the `Error` ones, or you could want to collect all the `Ok` elements as long as there are no `Error`s, in which case return just the first of them. And so on.

Comment: You could even "Aggregate/Fold/Reduce the OKs, and list concat the errors"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the options you mention can be useful in some cases.

- `list<Result<decimal, string>>` represents a case where individual values may be invalid, but the transformation of the list itself cannot fail
- `Result<list<Result<decimal, string>>, string>` represents a case where individual values may be invalid and there is also some other reason for which the list processing itself may fail
- `Result<decimal list, string list>` represents the case where you either process the whole list correctly, or the processing fails and you collect multiple errors along the way.

I think the interesting case is the last one - if you wanted to either get a valid list or a list of parsing errors, you could write the following:

```
let merged = output |> List.fold (fun res v ->
  match v, res with
  | Ok v, Ok res -> Ok(v::res)
  | Ok _, Error errs -> Error(errs)
  | Error e, Error errs -> Error(e::errs)
  | Error e, Ok _ -> Error [e]) (Ok [])
```

Comment: this is a great answer, well beyond the classic "it depends" response :) ...now, what about concerns related to traversing "too many times"? ...hmm, it looks like your `merged` function is addressing this concern